EntityFramwork Core - Case Sensitivity is not working when comparing two strings
I have this in my Application:
    public class PostLoginData
    {
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }

And this endpoint that compares if the user exists:
HttpPost]
    [Route("SubmitLogin")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SubmitLogin([FromBody] PostLoginData data)
    {

        var ctx = new SmurfdbContext();

        TblUser user = await ctx.TblUsers.Where(x => x.Email == data.email && x.Password == data.password).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        if (user != null)
        {

            if (user.VerifiedEmail == true)
            {
                return Ok(new { success = true, id = user.Guid, image = user.AvatarImage, avatarIndex = user.Avatar });
            }
            else
            {
                return Ok(new { error = "notEmailVerified", success = false });
            }


        }
        else
        {

            return Ok(new { error = "notFoundUser", success = false });
        }

    }

The password in the database TblUsers = "allafi01F!"
but when I send the request from the UI using Android JAVA and type in Allafi01F! the the user is found even when the first letter in the password should be a lowercase "a".
I have put a breakpoint in the Java code and the data is getting passwed correctly.
Not sure why this is happening never happened to me before.
I tested this in Swagger and still finds the user even when it is case sensitive.

I sincerely hope you are not storing plain-text passwords in your database, you need to salt-and-hash them. And why not use ASP.Net's excellent identity system rather than rolling your own?

+1, Never store passwords in your database. When you set a password, create a hash and store the hash. When you check a password, hash what was entered and compare the hash with the DB value. The reason your case sensitive check is failing is the Collation on the database being Case Insensitive. (Default in SQL Server, other databases may default to CI or CS. Collation can be set on individual fields, and should be case sensitive for properly hashed values as well.

Yes, i understand from the two comments, I am salting and hashing the passwords now. Good call from you guys

It had to do with the "Collation" in the database design for SQL. The key to the answer is LINQ to Entities case sensitive comparison.
I changed the Collation from SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS to SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS.
